# Cloning HTML Element with the Events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML image element as shown below:

```
var actionImage = $("<img></img>");
    actionImage.attr("id", getRandomString()); 
    actionImage.attr("width", "16").attr("height", "16").attr("src", "Action_normal.png");
    actionImage.attr("style", "cursor: hand;");
    actionImage.bind('mouseover', function() {
        OnMouseOver($(this).get(0));              
    });
```

When I clone this element I loose the mouseover event. How can I make sure that the events are also cloned.

Comment: `$(this).get(0)` is just wrong. It's the exact same as simply doing `this`. Try: `alert($(this).get(0) === this); // true`

Comment: You might also consider reducing your 5 `.attr()` calls down to just one, by passing a single object to set the attributes. `actionImage.attr({id:getRandomString(), width:16, height:16 ...})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) takes a boolean parameter that, when it's true (which isn't the default), conserves data and events.  You want `$actionImage.clone(true)`.

And as @Purmou mentions, you could also do this by binding your JS events via `on` or `delegate`, to avoid this very problem.

Comment: Nice - didn't know that.  Your answer is definitely better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

When passing `true` to the `clone()` method in JQuery, event handlers are copied too. So just use `$("#myElementId").clone(true)`.

Answer (score 1):

`.clone` has a `[withDataAndEvents]` option that can be set to `true`:

> **withDataAndEvents**
>
> A Boolean indicating whether event handlers should
> be copied along with the elements. As of jQuery 1.4, element data will
> be copied as well.

*Source: http://api.jquery.com/clone/*

This has been an option since 1.0.